# for each if true fetch mysqli result

Tags: php

Hello i try to print all results from a table where time  is in futre:
thank you for any help or tips.

```
<?php
function show_entrys($all){

$connectSQL = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Timur", "eventdb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

foreach ($all as $one){
         $Eid = $one['event_id'];
             $Tid = $one['time_id'];
     $dtA = $one['endtime'];
     $dtB = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $date1 = strtotime("7 February 2008"); 
       $date2 = strtotime("8 February 2008");
```

actually i'd like to check with $dtB and $dtA:

```
    SQL QUERY QUESRION:
    can i make a innerjoin query with the following query? : "select starttime, endtime from time where id = $ "
```

if not i will solve this in anotherway. here comes the query:

```
if($date2 > $date1){ 
   $sql = $connectSQL->query("SELECT name, description, genre_id, photo FROM eventWHER id=$Eid");
```

here i want to fetch every entry in the table into an array

```
}
else {
  echo" no events in the future ";
    }
   }

while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $events[] = $row;
                }
        foreach ($events as $one){
        echo $one['name'];
        echo $one['description'];
        echo $one['genre_id'];
        echo $one['photo'];
        }
        mysqli_close($connectSQL);
}
```

everything works except that i use the while in the div.

Comment: This `FROM eventWHER id=$Eid"` should be `FROM event WHERE id=$Eid"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse MySQL results inside If statement. Otherwise, you will only have the last run of foreach ($all as $one).

Then, the query is `FROM event WHERE id=$Eid`, instead of `FROM eventWHER id=$Eid`.

```
<?php
function show_entrys($all){

$connectSQL = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Timur", "eventdb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

foreach ($all as $one){
         $Eid = $one['event_id'];
     $dtA = $one['endtime'];
     $dtB = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $date1 = strtotime("7 February 2008"); 
       $date2 = strtotime("8 February 2008"); 

if($date2 > $date1){ 
    $sql = $connectSQL->query("SELECT name, description, genre_id, photo FROM event WHERE id=$Eid");

while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $events[] = $row;
                }
foreach ($events as $one){
    echo $one['name'];
    echo $one['description'];
    echo $one['genre_id'];
    echo $one['photo'];
    }
}

   }
   else
  echo" no events in the future ";
   }
mysqli_close($connectSQL);
```